# nginx one domain few websites

Tags: nginx, php

I am having problem with configuration of nginx for few pages on one domain. For example we have example.com. This page allows u to buy some goods, but I would like to seperate pages for continents. So I created /usr/share/nginx/europe, /usr/share/nginx/asia each folder have it owns files, database etc. I am trying to configurate it but i dunno know how. Should I make some subdomains instead? Cannot I use for example: example.com/asia example.com/europe in /etc/nging/sites-enabled I ve created two files europe and asia:

```
server {
   listen   80;
   root /usr/share/nginx/europe; 
   index index.html index.htm index.php;
   server_name example.com/europe;
   access_log /var/log/nginx/test1_access.log;
   error_log /var/log/nginx/test1_error.log;

   location /blog.php$ {
        include /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME$document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    }
}

server {
    listen   80;
    root /usr/share/nginx/asia; 
    index index.html index.htm index.php;
    server_name example.com/asia;
    access_log /var/log/nginx/asia_access.log;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/asia_error.log;

    location /blog.php$ {
        include /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME$document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you want subdomains (e.g. asia.example.com) or one site (e.g. example.com/asia)?

Comment: `server_name example.com/asia` is invalid format. `server_name` only referes to domain name.

Comment: example.com/asia and example.com/europe I want to avoid subdomains

Answer (score 0):

You can't have server_name with URI element. **Try this instead**:

```
server {
   listen   80;
   server_name example.com;



    location /europe/ {
      root /usr/share/nginx/europe; 
      index index.html index.htm index.php;
      access_log /var/log/nginx/test1_access.log;
      error_log /var/log/nginx/test1_error.log;

      location ~* \blog.php$ {
          include /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params;
          fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
          fastcgi_index index.php;
          fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME$document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
      }
    }

    location /asia/ {
      root /usr/share/nginx/asia; 
      index index.html index.htm index.php;
      access_log /var/log/nginx/asia_access.log;
      error_log /var/log/nginx/asia_error.log;

      location ~* \blog.php$ {
          include /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params;
          fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
          fastcgi_index index.php;
          fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME$document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
      }
    }
}
```

Comment: I am using 
    location ~ \.php $ {
instead 
    location ~* \blog.php $ {

and i gets:
2015/04/15 09:13:35 [emerg] 1889#0: invalid number of arguments in "fastcgi_param" directive in /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/test1:15